# Unable to disable Ctrl + Alt + Backspace (kills Server X / session). Linux Mint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, x-server

I accidentally killed a session with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Backspace` (actually I pressed `Shift` too but works the same way) and decided I don't want that combination to do that (I have to use similar combinations often and it doesn't ask for confirmation if pressed accidentally).

There were **similar questions:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005618/change-ctrlaltbackspace-to-restart-x-server and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357400/change-shortcut-that-restarts-x-server-ctrl-alt-backspace . But although the alternative shortcut is a good idea, they don't say how to disable it.

I tried **an answer** from [Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to kill X server can't be disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149062/ctrlaltbackspace-to-kill-x-server-cant-be-disabled) that asks to check for the results of

```
xmodmap -pke | grep -i server
```

but this doesn't find anything over the results.

I also **tried to remove the shortcut** both from the **keyboard shortcuts configuration** (Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > System > Close session) and also by not enabling this option following the steps of **this question:**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace
. That is writing on terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and leaving everything as it is until the screen with the question

> By default the combination Control+Alt+Backspace does not do anything. If you want, you can use it to terminate X Server.
> Do you want to use Control+Alt+Backspace to kill X Server? ·Yes ·No

I selected No (as it was by default) but still get the unwanted behaviour.

Screenshot with the enabling option for shortcut to kill X Server - in catalan, not english, just to show how it looks:
[image: Screenshot with the enabling option for shortcut to kill X Server - in catalan, not english, just to show how it looks]

On the file `/etc/default/keyboard` I have:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

I don't know if should report as a bug or there's another layer that overrides this configuration that I'm not aware of.

My system: Kernel: 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0
Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa
base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Answer (score 1):

Go to Menu > System Settings > Keyboard Layouts

Click on Options button, and expand Key sequence to kill the X server and deselected the ctrl+Alt+Backspace. Then close all windows and try this Ctrl-Alt-Backspace again. There should be no more hard reset and hard logout. Just nothing.
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! finally saving waste of time

Comment: And this is successfully ignored by Xorg and kills the server anyway.